# Is it a good practise, to isolate PHP code into different functions without a specific need?

Tags: php, performance, function, variables

I am writing php code in order to define some information (in the beginning of an HTMl page), and then to use the defined variables through out the page itself.

If I have some peace of code, that should be called repeatedly, then no doubt I use functions for it. But in this case, I am asking about the code, that runs only once on the page and defines some information, that will be later used. But I try to figure out, what would be the best practice.

In one case, I write all of the code, that creates/gets/processes information, just by itself.

```
$x = 10;
$select = $db->some_query (that is pseudo code...)
$x = $x + $select;

echo $x;
```

In another case, I isolate it into different functions by it's meaning. And then just call those functions, from the beginning of the script. In this case, I have to make variables, that I want to use in other places, global.

```
define_x_variable($db);

function define_x_variable($db) {
    global x;

    $x = 10;
    $select = $db->some_query (that is pseudo code...)
    $x = $x + $select;
}

echo $x;
```

So, the reason, why I use the second approach, is that:

- it is easier to see, what a certain peace of code accomplishes (by the name of a function) [on the other hand, it can be done by php comments...]
- variables used in the function don't get anywhere outside of this very function (so, in this case `$select` variable is not defined outside of this function. So, if I decide to use this variable again for some other case, I would not have to overwrite it. And I would not accidentaly use it's previous meaning)
- I have only certain variables accessed, via the whole script (ex.: variable `$x`), which I define myself.

So, the only problem, is that I am not sure, whether it is a good practice to code this way. I have read, that global variables have a bad rap and are not recommended to be used. Also I think, that I might be over-complicating things.

So what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second option is the best approach.

You applied by yourself the separation of concerns principle

- Gather data
- Format data
- Display data
- And so on...
  More of this here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

If you are ever interested , you can go check in PHP frameworks like Symfony, wich works hard to provide some goos structure to the code.

You should always provide clean well organized code, with functions limited to a little piece of work. You can then make it perfect, and get a more maintainable software at the end.

so, be well organized first, the look at performance issues if there are.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to write a function for this. Just because, If you want any *change* in that would be easy and when this same function is needed somewhere in our application, we can *reuse* this.

Better to choose function writing.

Thanks